# react-query fetched data to useState causing error

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm trying to assign the data fetched through `useQuery` to a state to handle a better conditional rendering based on if the request is empty or not.

At the moment, what I'm trying to do looks like the following:

```
...
const [userLists, setUserLists] = useState({});
...
const lists = useQuery(["lists"], api.fetchLists);

  if(lists.isLoading){
    //
  } else {
    setUserLists(lists.data.lists); // this line is causing the issue
  }
```

The browser is returning me a `Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

Why would this happen? How is it possible to actually put the result in a useState hook?

Comment: Like the error describes, it happens because different states update each other and creates an infinite loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this is causing an infinite loop because you are setting state inside the component. To prevent this please use useEffect like this:

```
const [userLists, setUserLists] = useState({});
...
const lists = useQuery(["lists"], api.fetchLists);

useEffect(() => {
    if (lists.isLoading) {
        // any loading state you might have
    } else {
        setUserLists(lists.data.lists); // this line is causing the issue
    }
}, [lists])
```

Comment: This worked! Just gotta remove the `isLoading`

Comment: while this answer works, I would generally question why you would need to "copy" data from react-query into local state? You can just work with `lists.data.lists` directly ?

Answer (score 0):

Your component goes into the loop because you are checking for the loading state first and setting the state in the else block.

Therefore, else block gets calls multiple times. Which causes the `Too many re-renders`

try the following code

```
     ...
    const [userLists, setUserLists] = useState({});
    ...
    const lists = useQuery(["lists"], api.fetchLists);

    if(lists.isLoading){
      // set loading here or render loading component
    }

    if(!lists.isLoading && !lists.error){
      setUserLists(lists.data.lists); // this line is causing the issue
    }
```

Comment: Still entering on an infinite loop :(

Comment: then it could be happening somewhere else.

Comment: But its weird because once I coment `setUserLists(lists.data.lists);` everything works just fine.